# Counting records on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is to count the number of transactions that are happened in the tables. Below is my query:

```
select tt.transaction_key, tt.description, t.mode, count(t.TransactionType) as Frequency
from transaction_names tt left join
     transaction_report_data t
     on tt.transaction_key = t.TransactionType and
        t.created >='2017-04-11' and t.created <= '2018-04-13'
group by tt.transaction_key, tt.description, t.mode;
```

I also need the count/frequency for the number of transactions which are successful only or which has t.status = 'success'.

Please help how can I adjust this 'where' clause to count this type of records also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a case with aggregate like below

```
select 
tt.transaction_key, 
tt.description, 
t.mode, 
count(t.TransactionType) as Frequency,
Sum(case when t.status='success' then 1 else 0 end) as SuccessfulTransactions
from transaction_names tt left join
     transaction_report_data t
     on tt.transaction_key = t.TransactionType and
        t.created >='2017-04-11' and t.created <= '2018-04-13'
group by tt.transaction_key, tt.description, t.mode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    tt.transaction_key,
    tt.[Description],
    t.mode,
    COUNT(t.TransactionType) AS Frequency,
    Success = SUM(CASE WHEN T.[Status]='Success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM transaction_names tt
       LEFT JOIN transaction_report_data t 
          ON tt.transaction_key = t.TransactionType
             AND t.created >= '2017-04-11'
             AND t.created <= '2018-04-13'
       GROUP BY 
          tt.transaction_key,
          tt.[Description],
          t.mode;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tt.transaction_key, tt.description, t.mode, count(t.TransactionType) as Frequency
from transaction_names tt left join
     transaction_report_data t
     on tt.transaction_key = t.TransactionType and
        t.created >='2017-04-11' and t.created <= '2018-04-13'
group by tt.transaction_key, tt.description, t.mode, t.status
having t.status = 'success'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've edited your answer to provide better formatting for the code. In the future, you can use four spaces to indent your code to create a code block. In addition, It would be great if you could provide some explanation to your answer, as code-only answers generally get removed/downvoted.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me!!